# Superfluous WriteHeader and no response

Tags: go, gorilla, go-http

I'm writing an HTTP API that sends requests to a WebSocket gateway. I'm using `go1.14.7` and `gorilla/mux` `v1.8.0`. The code will be cross-compiled using `GOOS=linux` `GOARCH=arm` `GOARM=7`.

My problems are the following:

- `respondBadRequest()` always logs this even though I never use `WriteHeader`:

  - `http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.(*HttpHandler).respondBadRequest`
- The API response is always `200 OK` even when `respondBadRequest()` is called
- The API response always has an empty body

I'm completely new to Go. Below is my code structure.

```golang
type HttpHandler struct {
  gateway Gateway
}

func (h *HttpHandler) respondSuccess(w http.ResponseWriter, text string) {
  w.Write([]byte(text))
}

func (h *HttpHandler) respondBadRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, text string) {
  http.Error(w, text, http.StatusBadRequest)
}

func (h *HttpHandler) respondError(w http.ResponseWriter, text string) {
  http.Error(w, text, http.StatusInternalServerError)
}

func (h *HttpHandler) OnFoobar(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  f := func(success bool, e error) {
    if e != nil {
      h.respondError(w, e.Error())
    } else if success {
      h.respondSuccess(w, "Foobar Accepted")
    } else {
      h.respondBadRequest(w, "Unknown Foobar")
    }
  }
  //...
  e := h.gateway.Foobar(f)
  if e != nil {
    log.Println(e)
  }
}

//...

httpHandler := &HttpHandler{
  gateway: gateway,
}

r := mux.NewRouter()

r.HandleFunc("/foobar", httpHandler.OnFoobar)

http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
```

Comment: If you write any part of a response, `WriteHeader` is already called. You can't send a different header after you've already written a response.

Comment: You're not calling `WriteHeader` directly, but you're calling it indirectly in several places; if you call `Write` and `WriteHeader` hasn't already been called, `Write` will call `WriteHeader(200)` (as stated in the docs). `http.Error` also calls `WriteHeader`. If you want to respond with an error, you have to do so *before* calling `Write` to send any body content (in an HTTP response, the status and headers *must* precede the response body).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I don't really understand what you mean. I'm aware that any `Write` will call `WriteHeader` since I tried to debug my issue before posting here. My issue is that I don't understand where that first `Write` happens that makes mine superfluous. Apparently in `gateway.Foobar()`, but I can't tell why or how to restructure this so that it doesn't interfere with my surrounding API code.

Comment: `f` looks like a callback, so I guess `Foobar` is asynchronous? Is it doing it's job in a goroutine? If so the handler `OnFoobar` does not wait for `Foobar` to finish and when it exits, if `w` hasn't been written to yet, Go's serve mux will write to it 200ok by default, then later when `Foobar`'s done and it invokes the callback you get the error you get.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, it's asynchronous and thanks for actually understanding the issue... Now that you mention it, it does seem obvious. I guess I could use a channel to delay `OnFinish()` until `f()` is done. Or is there a smarter way around this?

Comment: @Steffen that seems like unnecessary complexity to me, why don't you remove the callback, make Foobar synchronous, have it return an error that can be inspected to then decide upon the proper status code. Note that in Go the standard router, and I'm pretty sure gorilla/mux as well, already handle each request in a separate goroutine, so you don't have to roll  your own asynchronicity.

Comment: @mkopriva Unfortunately `Foobar` is from a third-party package I have no control over.

Comment: @Steffen in that case use a `sync.WaitGroup`.

Comment: @Steffen something like this should do, I believe: https://play.golang.org/p/_2DkCVXmhcS

Comment: @mkopriva I tried a channel and it works. Thanks so much. I have a look at `sync.WaitGroup` and answer my (apparently terrible...) question later.

Answer (score 1):

So as @mkopriva pointed out `f` is rather obviously called after `OnFoobar` already finished and wrote an implicit empty response. His fix using `sync.WaitGroup`:

```golang
func (h *HttpHandler) OnFoobar(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
  wg.Add(1)
  f := func(success bool, e error) {
    if e != nil {
      h.respondError(w, e.Error())
    } else if success {
      h.respondSuccess(w, "Foobar Accepted")
    } else {
      h.respondBadRequest(w, "Unknown Foobar")
    }
    wg.Done()
  }
  //...
  e := h.gateway.Foobar(f)
  if e != nil {
    log.Println(e)
  }
  wg.Wait()
}
```